# how to create dhcp server master

Tags: isc-dhcpd, proxmox

i want to create a seprate dhcp server that all other servers whose proxmox has been installed on them, get static IP address by dchp server through MAC Address of virtual machines(proxmox servers)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L. We would like a question to show research. Could you please explain what you've found out so far, and what problems you are hitting?

Comment: @Edward thanks! update request.